# Can pip list its binary wheels?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to resolve a behavior difference between two python installations that are usually deterministic and have the same python pip packages installed.

I suspect different .so files. Is there a way to see which binaries binary wheels pip has installed, and for which architectures?

Update --

```
% pip show
Name: scipy
Version: 1.0.0rc1
Summary: SciPy: Scientific Library for Python
Home-page: https://www.scipy.org
Author: SciPy Developers
Author-email: scipy-dev@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy
```

The above package depends on things like `libopenblas` which must be compiled. I'm not sure if pip used the system installation, or compiled BLAS during a pip install, or used as precompiled version of BLAS for a i386, or i686 -- who knows.

The above case I have:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/.libs/libopenblasp-r0-39a31c03.2.18.so
```

I'd like to see which packages have## Heading ## differences in their installed .sos on different systems.

Comment: use python code: use "pip list" command ( catch its output ), then put each of that package_name on "pip show" command with "for", for show their info.

Comment: `pip list` and `pip show <package_name>` are the easiest way to quickly check as @DRPK mentions, but if you are digging into individual files you can see where your site packages are installed for each python instance with opening up the python IDLE or from CLI then `import site` `site.getsitepackages()` which will then return something like `['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']` where you can verify the files are the same, just in case something odd was happening at one and not the other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information is there, but you'll have to dig around in `dist-info` and/or `egg-info` subdirectories to find it.

- Binary distributions include a `RECORD` file in their metadata subdirectory.
- Source distributions include an `installed-files.txt` file in their metadata subdirectory.

The `RECORD` files are csv lines of (path, hash, size) as documented in [PEP-376](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/).  The older `installed-files.txt` from an egg is just the filenames, and you'll have to stat those files manually.

As a simple example, I have source and binary distributions of my package [copyingmock](https://github.com/wimglenn/copyingmock) available on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/copyingmock).  With the binary distribution installed (`pip install copyingmock`):

```
$ pip show --files copyingmock
Name: copyingmock
Version: 0.1
Summary: A subclass of MagicMock that copies the arguments
Home-page: https://github.com/wimglenn/copyingmock
Author: Wim Glenn
Author-email: hey@wimglenn.com
License: MIT
Location: /tmp/blah/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  __pycache__/copyingmock.cpython-36.pyc
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/INSTALLER
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/LICENSE.txt
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/METADATA
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/RECORD
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json
  copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
  copyingmock.py
$ cat venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/RECORD 
copyingmock.py,sha256=DoLAuaS7KqGT87BIlD93G1M7q9bNWgHYu1m1TZP1D1g,345
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst,sha256=L_0CS_8XNYgAVfq3tj3GZEYg_9vML9nDP-FUU37GIbs,1541
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/LICENSE.txt,sha256=sDdX5cBRRpk3rmZ8hbYEfAUIYRdDqrlXmChOUkqf62o,1066
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/METADATA,sha256=bKJ5RXwvj0rGrg22p4K91WiJoLM5MqLHYqlpWYWUhPU,2031
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/RECORD,,
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL,sha256=5wvfB7GvgZAbKBSE9uX9Zbi6LCL-_KgezgHblXhCRnM,113
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json,sha256=SLtuqq4tUGr0A2h4hQnZEdPIm_4MrvcunLzP-_1I7Qc,677
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt,sha256=X3FsY_0npOxR5rKvOJ-b2rdiNfSiIivwVKN4JgY7cac,12
copyingmock-0.1.dist-info/INSTALLER,sha256=zuuue4knoyJ-UwPPXg8fezS7VCrXJQrAP7zeNuwvFQg,4
__pycache__/copyingmock.cpython-36.pyc,,
```

Then forcing to reinstall with the source distribution (`pip uninstall copyingmock` and then `pip install --no-binary=copyingmock copyingmock`):

```
$ pip show --files copyingmock
Name: copyingmock
Version: 0.1
Summary: A subclass of MagicMock that copies the arguments
Home-page: https://github.com/wimglenn/copyingmock
Author: Wim Glenn
Author-email: hey@wimglenn.com
License: MIT
Location: /tmp/blah/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  __pycache__/copyingmock.cpython-36.pyc
  copyingmock-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  copyingmock-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
  copyingmock-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  copyingmock-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/top_level.txt
  copyingmock.py
$ cat venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/copyingmock-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/installed-files.txt 
../copyingmock.py
../__pycache__/copyingmock.cpython-36.pyc
dependency_links.txt
PKG-INFO
top_level.txt
SOURCES.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. ```pip show --files scipy  | grep -e \\.so``` let's me find the .sos for a single package, altough its a little short on information such as which architecture it was compiled for, etc... that might show differences. I can try checksumming the .so files, but I suspect and where compiled with debug info with render this useless.